# Is the command `ruby` in my shell a REPL of ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, bash, shell

In bash under Ubuntu, when I run `ruby` as a command, it doesn't repond, neither does it say anything wrong. It doesn't seem like a REPL of ruby language.

```
$ ruby
```

`man ruby` says it is a programming language

```
RUBY(1)                Ruby Programmers Reference Guide               RUBY(1)

NAME
     ruby — Interpreted object-oriented scripting language

SYNOPSIS
     ruby [--copyright] [--version] [-Sacdlnpswvy] [-0[octal]] [-C directory]
          [-F pattern] [-I directory] [-K c] [-T[level]] [-e command]
          [-i[extension]] [-r library] [-x[directory]] [--] [program_file]
          [argument ...]

DESCRIPTION
     Ruby is an interpreted scripting language for quick and easy object-ori‐
     ented programming.  It has many features to process text files and to do
     system management tasks (as in Perl).  It is simple, straight-forward,
     and extensible.
```

What is the command `ruby`?

Is `ruby` the compiler of `ruby`, just like `gcc` for `C`?

If `ruby` isn't a command, why doesn't it say something wrong?

For example C is a programming language, but `C` isn't a command

```
$ C
C: command not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: `ruby` is the interpreter. If you don't feed it a script to execute (e.g. `ruby foo.rb`), it expects it in STDIN.  `irb` or `pry` are good Ruby REPL programs.

Comment: For a programming language, is a REPL an interpreter? Is an interpreter not necessarily a REPL?

Comment: A REPL typically uses an interpreter, but an interpreter is not a REPL. irb is a REPL. It reads input, uses Ruby to execute that input, prints the resulting output, and loops.

Comment: @meagar: thanks. why is `ruby` an interpreter, not a compiler?

Comment: Because it interprets, not compiles. Seriously. Ruby is an interpreted language. Ruby programs are distributed as source code, and cannot be run without a Ruby interpreter.  C++ or Java  are examples of compiled languages, where a compiler produces a stand-alone distributed executable from the source code.

Comment: @meagar: that's not true. If `ruby` is YARV or Rubinius, then it *is* a compiler. YARV and Rubinius *always* compile Ruby, they *never* interpret it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're over-complicating things with technical nitpicking.

Answer (score 6):

`ruby`, when called with no arguments, expects a ruby program from STDIN to execute:

```
llama@llama:~$ ruby
puts 1+1
2
llama@llama:~$
```

(note that I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for EOF after typing the code)

For a REPL, try `irb` (interactive Ruby), which is built-in to Ruby with a fresh install:

```
llama@llama:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> 1+1
=> 2
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: @August Possibly, but it's not built-in to Ruby (i.e. installed "by default" when Ruby is installed).